# Close BarcodeScanner Ionic Native Plugin with timeout

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

this is my scenario: I have a barcodeScanner ionic plugin in my Ionic application, that is installed on a tablet where I cannot use hardware buttons.

My code:

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan(option).then((result) => {
            console.dir(
                "We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled
            );

            this.product_code = result.text;
            if(result.text !== "" && result.text !== null)
            {
                return this.searchByBarcode(result.text);
            }
        }, (err) => {
            // An error occurred
        });
```

**Question**

Is there a way to close the plugin after a certain amount of time if no barcode is scanned (or to insert a software button inside the plugin)?